# Cloth wont collide

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I want this plane to fall onto the cube like a blanket and I use collision on the cube and cloth on the plane, but when I play animation the plane falls half way through the cube and then folds.

I want it to land on top of the cube.

[image]

Comment: subdivide the blanket.. the more faces it has the better...

Answer (score 1):

**Updated solution:**

I checked the file and found that in the **Collision** settings, you had the "Single sided" option checked on your cube.003 object.

Solution is to switch that off, then the plane stopps on top of the cube.003 as wanted, looks like this:
[image]

For the further simulation i would suggest to add a subdivision surface modifier on the plane, but i believe that will be mentioned in the tutorial you follow.

Happy Blending.

Comment: thank you fore answer but it did not work. I went into edit mode and Shift+N but it not work. I even tried to make a new plane and new cube but same thing happen :(

Comment: Did you by chance have nothing selected in edit mode before you pressed Shift+N?
I updated the answer, since functions that regard normals only work on selections.

Comment: I had everything selected but it still does the same weird thing.. :(

Comment: Would you mind sharing your file? [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so i could take a look?

Comment: Okey! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=zlKXKBYZ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/zlKXKBYZ/)

Comment: Updated the answer, should it solve your problem, please consider to accept it.